# Ayuda con objeto javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema al querer recorrer un objeto con.

```
for(var i in object){
    console.log(object[i]);
}
```

no muestra nada, no ingresa al for. además cuando realizo

```
console.log(object); // si muestra valores
console.log(Object.keys(object).length); //muestra 0
console.log(object['9']); //muestra undefined
```

Adjunto imagen del resultado. Espero puedan ayudarme por favor.
[image]

Comment: Y la definición del objeto?

Comment: el ciclo es correcto, el codigo anterior al ciclo for funciona? capaz que nunca llega por otra razon.

Comment: Esto es todo lo que tengo: 
_do_search: function () {
     this._super.apply(this, arguments);
     console.log(this.objeto);
     console.log(Object.keys(this.objeto).length);
     console.log(this.objeto['9']);
}

Comment: Intenta recorrerlo con esta alternativa Object.keys(object).forEach(function(prop) {console.log(object[prop]); });

Comment: En el log tenés Object con mayuscula en celeste vs object con miúscula en azul.

Comment: intenta `objecto.toSource()` o `JSON.stringify(objeto)`

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

Es porque al poner `console.log(object)` el navegador guarda un puntero y no el valor del objeto.

**Estás viendo el valor que tiene en el objeto en el momento en que estás mirando y no en el momento en que se ejecutó el `console.log`.**

## Respuesta larga

Al hacer `console.log(variable)` el navegador pone en la pila consola el valor de la variable. Cuando la variable no es un objeto (o sea es type `number`, `string`, `boolean`, etc) se almacena dicho valor, cuando la variable es un objeto se almacena la dirección de memoria de ese objeto.

Lo que ves al inspeccionar la consola es el estado actual de ese objeto (sea un `Object` o un `Array` o similar).

Entonces si lo que deseas es mostrar el estado actual del objeto vas a tener que usar alguna librería que pase el objeto a texto. Cuidado con `JSON` (que las funciones las muestra como null y las fechas como string). Dependiendo de lo que quieras mostrar deberás usar una u otra librería.

Otra alternativa es poner un "breakpoint" en el código para que te muestre el valor actual simplemente porque interrumpes el código en el momento que te interesa.

## Demostración

Para los que no creen que esto funciona así (por lo menos en Chrome) pueden probarlo poniendo el siguiente código en un archivo.html

```
<p>Prueba</p>
<script>
var object={}
console.log("antes");
console.log(object);
console.log("despues");
object.algo="ahora tiene algo";
</script>
```

Luego hagan doble click en el archivo (si tienen el chrome como navegador predeterminado) si no pónganlo en la barra de direcciones. Luego presionen `F12` vayan a la solapa de la consola, abran donde dicen `object` y verán algo parecido a esto:

[image: ejemplo de console en chrome]

### Curiosidades (y precisiones)

En `Chrome` cuando se tipean comandos en la consola, los console.log muestran al lado del tipo (Object) un resumen del contenido. Gracias a eso se puede ver el valor que tenía un objeto originalmente. Pero si la flecha para mirar el contenido se toca después de cambiar el objeto lo que se muestre será lo nuevo y no lo original.

Pareciera ser que el comportamiento preciso es: al expandir un objeto en la consola del `Chrome` muestra el contenido que tiene al momento de expandirlo por primera vez: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tX0I.jpg

Comment: De qué hablas? console.log(obj) simplemente imprime el estado del objeto, no importa si luego éste cambia, una vez impreso, los valores en el log no cambian... y de hacerlo entonces el compartamiento es erróneo y no w3c compatible https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log

Comment: Hola @EduenSarceño. Hablo de lo que ocurre. De lo que he experimentado. El mundo es así, hay software que no cumple los estándares, hay usuarios que se topan con ello y otros usuarios que tratan de explicar por qué eso ocurre (aunque algunos opinen que eso no debería ocurrir). Agregué en la respuesta una "demo" para que puedas experimentarlo tu mismo.

Comment: También hay usuarios que votan negativamente una respuesta porque se enojan con lo que ahí se describe en lugar de juzgar su correctitud o utilidad. Por suerte StackOverflow permite cambiar los propios votos y borrar los comentarios que uno juzque inapropiados.

Comment: Hola @Emilio Platezer,  aún así eso no responde la pregunta del usuario, que cambie o no cambie la información en el log es irrelevante. Y cada quién es libre de votar a su propio criterio, usar software que no sigue estándares debería de evitarse a toda costa.

Comment: También es bueno mencionar que el problema es más específico a tu navegador que en otros... incluyendo navegadores del mismo fabricante  http://imgur.com/a/h9Wbk

Comment: @EduenSarceño gracias por tus opiniones. Despertaste mi curiosidad y probé con otros navegadores que tengo instalados. Firefox y Safari funcionan como el Chrome (mostrando el valor al momento de mirar). En Edge funciona bien (mostrando el valor que tenía en el momento de ejecutar el `console.log`). De los 4 que revisé el que más se parece (en el diseño gráfico) al del dibujo del usuario que preguntó es el Chrome. Creo entonces que la explicación que dí es útil porque explica por qué no funciona el código como el usuario espera y por qué ve lo que ve. Pero es una creencia, puedo equivocarme.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61802/discussion-between-eduen-sarceno-and-emilio-platzer).

Answer (score -1):

La pregunta es muy amplia, y más cuando nunca dan la definición del objeto, sin embargo responderé algunas posibles razones por la que cuál el código no funciona correctamente a lo esperado.

### Posibles causas

1. La definición del objeto define a `9` y `10` como no enumerables
2. Navegador con mala implementación de [Console](https://console.spec.whatwg.org)
3. `9` y `10` devuelven `undefined`

### Citando el código

> ```
> console.log(object); // si muestra valores
> console.log(Object.keys(object).length); //muestra 0
> console.log(object['9']); //muestra undefined
> ```

### Ejemplificando

`Object.keys` devuelve todas las propiedades `enumerables` así que si `9` y `10` no son enumerables, y son las únicas propiedades definidas en `object` entonces `Object.keys(object)` devolverá un arreglo de `0` elementos, para más información [ver aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)

supongamos que la definición de `object` sea la siguiente

```
var object = Object.defineProperties({},
{
    '9': {enumerable: false, get: function(){ return 'soy 9' }},
    '10':{enumerable: false, get: function(){ return 'soy 10'}}
})
```

Como puedes ver `9` y `10` son propiedades no enumerables, (no hace falta definirlo, porque por defecto toda propiedad se crea como no enumerable y no configurable al menos que se especifique lo contrario, así que incluir `enumerable: false` es redundate y solo por fines didáticos)

```
Object.keys(object).length // 0
```

La anterior línea devuelve un arreglo vacío puesto que `object` tiene solo propiedades `no enumerables`, así que `Object.keys(object).length` es `0`

```
for (var key in object) {
    console.log(object[key]) // no hace nada
}
```

El anterior `for..in` no hace nada, puesto que `for..in` solo itera en propiedades enumerables, [ver aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
object["9"] // 'soy 9'
object["10"] // 'soy 10'
```

No obstante si se pueden acceder a dichas propiedades, por lo que de no poder se debe a un compartamiento erróneo del navegador, a no ser claro que `9` y `10` devuelvan `undefined` al hacer `get`